# Dafny selection sort descending

Tags: arrays, selection-sort, dafny

I have the following method for performing selection sort in **descending order**. However, the **very first invariant** in the while loop is said to be not maintained by the loop, why is that the case?

```
 method sortDesc (a : array<int>) 
        modifies a;
        requires a != null;
        ensures forall m,n :: 0 <= m < n < a.Length ==> a[m] >= a[n];
        requires a.Length > 1;
        ensures multiset(a[..]) == multiset(old(a[..]));
    {
        var index := a.Length - 1;
        while(index > -1)
            invariant forall m,n :: 0 <= m <= index && index < n < a.Length ==> a[m] >= a[n];               // all elements that we have not sorted are bigger than any element we have sorted  !!!!!!!!!!!!
            invariant a.Length > index > -1;
            invariant forall k,l :: index < k < l < a.Length ==> a[k] >= a[l];                              //the part we have gone through is already sorted!!
            invariant multiset(a[..]) == multiset(old(a[..]));                                      // USED TO MAKE SURE ALL THE STARTING ELEMENTS ARE STILL THERE!!!!!
            decreases index;
        {
            var minIndex := findMinBetween(a, index, a.Length);
            if (a[index] < a[minIndex]) 
            {
                a[index], a[minIndex] := a[minIndex],a[index];                               //SWAP ELEMENTS!!!
            }
            if (index == 0)
            {
                return;
            }
            index := index - 1;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps the comparison `a[index] < a[minIndex]` is the wrong way around. You are trying to move the small stuff to the right, so if `a[minindex]` is smaller than `a[index]` you need to move it (`a[minindex]`) to the right.

Comment: It seems to me that the loop gaurd could be `index > 0` which avoids the ugly early return.  See https://rise4fun.com/Dafny/qF7T

Comment: thank you so much, you were right for both things! I had also messed up the parameters for findMinBetween, they should be `findMinBetween(a, 0, index);`